# Find the Ratio $BM \colon ME$

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

In Triangle $\Delta ABC$, the Point $D$ is on $BC$ such that $D$ divides $B$ and $C$ in the Ratio $1 \colon 3$ and there is a point $E$ on $CA$ such that $E$ divides $C$ and $A$ in ratio $1 \colon 3$. if $BE$ and $AD$ meet at Point $M$, Find $BM \colon ME$.

My Try: I assumed $C$ is $(0,0)$ ,$A(x_1,y_1)$ and $B(x_2,y_2)$. Then by Section formulae we have $D(\frac{3x_2}{4},\frac{3y_2}{4})$ and $E(\frac{x_1}{4},\frac{y_1}{4})$. Forming equations of $AD$ and $BE$ and solving thm to find $M$ is laborious. Can i have any other approache

Comment: It would be a good thing to add a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider

[image]

Area of triangle ABM$=3(x+4y)-3x=12y$

So for triangle ABD and ADC:

$$\frac{12y+y}{4x+3y}=\frac13$$
$$x=9y$$

So 
$$\frac{BM}{ME}=\frac{3y+y}{x}=\frac{4y}{9y}=\frac4 9$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $F=CM\cap AB$. [Ceva's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceva%27s_theorem) gives:

$$\frac{BD}{DC}\cdot\frac{CE}{EA}\cdot\frac{AF}{FB}=1$$
hence $\frac{AF}{FB}=9$, then [Van Obel's theorem](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/VanObel.shtml) gives:
$$\frac{BM}{ME}=\frac{BD}{DC}+\frac{BF}{FA}=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{9}=\color{red}{\frac{4}{9}}.$$

[image]

Comment: Had heard about Van Obel earlier, learnt it today. Thanks :) +1.